# Не работают библиотеки gsap в pycharm

Tags: javascript, pycharm

**Подключаю библиотеки в index.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>сайт</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/main.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'core/main.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TimelineLite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/plugins/BezierPlugin.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>Scroll Animation</h1>
</header>

<section class="animation">
    <img class="paper-plane" src="{% static 'img/fly.png' %}" alt="paper-plane"/>
</section>

<footer>
    <h1>Woooooo</h1>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

**Далее в main.js их не находит.**

```
const flightPath = {
    curviness: 1.25,
    autoRotate: true,
    values: [{x: 100, y: -20}]
};

const tween = new TimelineLite();

tween.add(
     TweenLite.to(".paper-plane", 1, {
        bezier: flightPath,
        ease: Power1.easeInOut
    })
);
```

Прошу помочь, не понимаю в чём ошибка

Comment: Возможно ваш main срабатывает раньше, чем успевают загрузиться библиотеки. Попробуйте скрипт поместить внищ всех тегов скрипт и добавить атрибут  [defer](https://learn.javascript.ru/script-async-defer)